# undefined binding in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, undefined

Being a beginner in developing JS apps, I am, for now, restricting myself to observing existing code and trying to reproduce it while fiddling with variable names (so I can see whether I've understood things properly).

This is what I've been doing with this [JS quiz code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365120/KnockoutJS-vs-Silverlight) written with KO.js... Here is "my" version (not many changes at all...)

http://jsfiddle.net/s6EsB/

My problem is that when I try to run the code, I get a "isCorrect is undefined" not in my script but in the KO library. When I comment the lines containing isCorrect in the HTML, I then get "correctNbrAnswers is undefined", still in the KO library...

It is like KO doesn't understand the data parameters I use in referring to the appropriate templates...

```
<script id="questionView" type="text/html">
        <div>Question <span data-bind="text: index"></span></div>
        <div data-bind="visible: selectedAnswer() === undefined">
            <div data-bind="text: questionText"></div>
            <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'answerView', foreach: answers }"></ul>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: selectedAnswer() !== undefined">
            <div data-bind="template: { name: 'questionResultView', data: selectedAnswer }"></div> <!-- isCorrect id defined for answers, so if KO respects this scope, this should work... But it doesn't! -->
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.nextQuestion">Next</a>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script id="questionResultView" type="text/html">
        <div data-bind="visible: isCorrect">Bonne réponse !</div> <!-- Returns isCorrect is undefined (knockout.js line blablabla) -->
        <div data-bind="visible: !isCorrect">Non. La bonne réponse était <span data-bind="text: $parent.correctAnswer.answerText"></span></div>
    </script>
```

I'd love it if anyone could shed some light on the matter...

Thank you!

Ari  ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `selectedAnswer` may or may not be `undefined`.  And that's fine usually, however the logic in your view is a bit flawed.

```
<script id="questionView" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="visible: selectedAnswer() === undefined">
        <!-- _visible_ if selectedAnswer is undefined -->
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: selectedAnswer() !== undefined">
        <!-- _not visible_ if selectedAnswer is undefined -->
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'questionResultView', data: selectedAnswer }"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Take note of the comments I've added.

The first `div` is *visible* when the `selectedAnswer` is `undefined`.  Meaning the body of the `div` is still evaluated, only the results are not made visible.

The second `div` is *not visible* when the `selectedAnswer` is `undefined`.  The body is still evaluated.  Since the template uses the `selectedAnswer`, it is attempting to render an `undefined` object.  You'll need to prevent the body of the second `div` from being evaluated when `selectedAnswer` is `undefined`.

---

There are a number of ways you can accomplish this but we'll stick to the easiest.

Change the `visible` binding on the second `div` to an `if` binding.  Refer to the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) for more information.  Basically it is a lot like the `visible` binding except it doesn't evaluate the body if the condition is not truthy, exactly what we want.

Comment: Hey Jeff, it worked!!! Thank you :) Can I ask you why you change "visible" to "if" only for the 2nd <div>? Why not change both?

Comment: You _could_ (and you probably should) but my answer was just addressing the immediate problem. Since both sections are mutually exclusive, it would definitely be a good idea to make _that_ one use the `if` binding too.